# Printing period after putting variable into quotes

Tags: java, quotes, period

The compiler doesn't like me putting the period into quotes after the variable which is in quotes:

```
(userString = "Bob";)

\""+userString+ "\"" ".";
```

My desired output is:

`"Bob".`

My question is how do I get the compiler to print that period after `"Bob"`?  Netbeans gives it an error for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You use `\"` for a double quotation character literal, everything else is the same as it would be for a string literal. Hence

`String userString = "\"Bob\".";`

is what you want.